# How do I remove a single HABTM associated item without deleting the item itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

How do you remove a HABTM associated item without deleting the item itself?

For example, say I have 3 Students that are in a Science class together.  How do I remove the Science objects from the StudentsClasses table without deleting the actual Science reference?  I'm guessing that    `Student.Classes.first.delete` isn't a good idea.

I'm using JavaScript with drag-and-drop for adding and removing, not check boxes.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I tend to use has_many :through, but have you tried

```
student.classes.delete(science)
```

I think needing to have the target object, not just the ID, is a limitation of HABTM (since the join table is abstracted away for your convenience).  If you use has_many :through you can operate directly on the join table (since you get a Model) and that lets you optimize this sort of thing into fewer queries.

```
def leave_class(class_id)
  ClassMembership.delete(:all, :conditions => ["student_id = ? and class_id = ?", self.id, class_id)
end
```

If you want the simplicity of HABTM you need to use

```
student.classes.delete(Class.find 2)
```

Also, calling a model "Class" is a really bad idea.  Use a name that isn't part of the core of Ruby!

Comment: Well the way it is currently set up, I must use params[:class_id] to perform Class.find_by_id then use the found class to do that.  It would be nice if I could just say "Student.class_ids.remove[2]".

Comment: That's the sort of think you need has_many :through for.  Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete multiple associated items you can use `*` and write:

```
student.classes.delete(*classes_array)
```