# Rails Remove child association from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this (Contract and Accessory are associated with has_and_belongs_to_many):

```
# Get the contract and specific accessory based on params
@contract  = Contract.find(params[:id])
@accessory = @contract.accessories.find(params[:accessory_id])
```

Now, I'm wanting to remove that specific accessory from @contract. I don't want to delete the record from the DB, but simply want to remove the association between the two.

What's the railsy way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

How about this:

```
@contract.accessories.delete(@accessory)
```

See also: [How do I remove a single HABTM associated item without deleting the item itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089892/rails-associations-how-do-i-remove-a-single-habtm-associated-item)

Comment: Yup, that simple! I noticed the question you had referred me to, but the way they explained it was strange. Thanks though!